# Is there a way to interrupt the training process?

Tags: python, multithreading, training-data, opencv

I'm new to **OpenCV** and I want to train my model using the **python** module (`opencv-python`).

This is my code:

```
def startTraining():
    trainingThread = Thread(target=trainModel, args=())

def trainModel():
    # some code to get the faces and the ids
    recognizer.train(faces, np.array(ids))

def stopTraining()
    # some code to kill the training process
```

And **it works** perfectly.

So this is my question: Is there a way to **interrupt this process** (to kill it, to stop it...)?

I don't need to be able to restart the process after that...
I don't know how to do that with **threading**.
I want to create a **function** to kill the process. (example)

Any help is useful, thanks.

Comment: What is `recognizer.train`?

Comment: You can't just kill threads from the outside (without extra modules that can be messy and almost dangerous); the threads will have to collaborate, by e.g. the training thread polling for a `threading.Event` having been set every now and then.

Comment: The recognizer is `cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()` and the train function is used in OpenCV to create a model.

Comment: It [doesn't look like you can interrupt the `.train()` function](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.3/dd/d65/classcv_1_1face_1_1FaceRecognizer.html#ac8680c2aa9649ad3f55e27761165c0d6).

Comment: And how can I kill it ? Even if it's dangerous...

Comment: You can't, since it's not a Python function (that you could inject an exception into). If you really need it to be interruptible, you will probably need to run it in a subprocess that you can kill on demand and start another one afterwards.

Comment: You want to be able to have it do it automatically, or you'll do it manually

Comment: how much time does training take? **why** do you need to abort this?

Comment: If you are running it from terminal just use ctrl+c

Comment: I need to do it automatically. The user can record his face, record another one, delete a face. So I code a soft to do it. But when the user record a new face, if the training is running, I want to kill it to reload the training data.